# SUBdomain redirection not working for https (apache)

Tags: domain-name-system, https, http, redirection

I have a problem with redirecting the address: aa.bb.cc to bb.cc/aa
DNS is under the control of OVH. Redirection works for http calls and redirects on a page that is https.
However, if he calls https://aa.bb.cc, he gets the response "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"
Can anyone point me in the direction?

Comment: `connection refused` indicates that nothing is listening on the requested port on that interface (in the case of https that would be 443).

Comment: @GeraldSchneider You're right. Except that https on port 443 for bb.cc works without any problems. And not redirection.

Comment: and bb.cc resolves to the same IP address as aa.bb.cc?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider yes